# Variants of Dirichlet function in pointwise continuity

Tags: analysis, pointwise-convergence

Suppose $f$ is a function from a complete metric space $X$ to a metric space $Y$, and suppose $Y$ has points $y_{0}$, $y_{1}$ such that the subsets $f^{-1}(y_{0})$ and $f^{-1}(y_{1})$ are both dense in $Y$.

- Show that $f$ is not a pointwise limit of continuous functions $X \to
     Y$.
- Show that in the above situation, if $f$ maps every point of $X$
  either to $y_{0}$ or to $y_{1}$ and if
  $f^{-1}(y_{1})$ is countable, then $f$ cannot even be expressed as a
  pointwise limit of functions $X \rightarrow Y$ that are continuous at
  all points of $f^{-1}(y_{1})$; but that it can be expressed as a
  pointwise limit of functions $X \rightarrow Y$ that are continuous at
  all points of $f^{-1}(y_{0})$.

**Questions:**

- I was wondering how to use Baire's theorem to prove the 1st bullet.
- How to prove the 2nd bullet? We can use the Dirichlet function to give a counterexample to the 1st part, but any direct proof?

Thank you.

Comment: "Now consider the sequence $(f_{n}(x_{n,n}))$, for a large $n$, $f_{n}(x_{n,n})$ is close to $f(x_{n,n}) = y_{0}$."
This is an invalid logic. For example, let $f_n(x) = x^n$ be defined on $[0,1]$. Then, $f_n(1 - n^{-1}) \to e^{-1}$ as $n \to \infty$ but $f(1 - n^{-1}) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ where $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n (x)$.

Comment: @DoyoungKim, what does your last equation mean? Do you implicitly assume that $f_{n}$ converges to $f$ for all $x$?

Comment: @DoyoungKim More accurately, your $f_{n}$ is not pointwise convergent.

Comment: My $f_n$ is pointwise convergent since it is defined on $[0,1]$. $f(x) = 0$ for any $0 \leq x < 1$, and $f(1) = 1$.